# Problema al mandar mensajes entre nodos elixir en localhost

Tags: elixir

Mi problema es el siguiente, quiero crear dos nodos elixir en dos terminales distintas en una misma máquina y permitir que el nodo cliente envíe mensajes al servidor. Para ello utilizo los siguientes comandos de elixir, primero creando ambos nodos(node1 y node2), luego conectándolos entre ellos, registrando uno de ellos como :server y finalmente intentando mandar un mensaje desde el otro nodo al server:

```
iex --name node1@127.0.0.1
iex(node1@127.0.0.1)1> Node.connect(:"node2@127.0.0.1")
iex(node1@127.0.0.1)4> Process.register(self(), :server)
iex(node2@127.0.0.1)2> send(:server,"hello")
```

Al tratar de hacer el send muestra el siguiente error de argumento, que parece indicar que no reconoce el átomo :server a pesar de que ambos nodos se encuentran conectados entre sí:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.send(:server, "hello")
```

Alguien propone alguna solución? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, estas en Stack Overflow en Español.

Comment: Perdón por la equivocación, ya lo he traducido.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor que lo hicieras usando GenServer: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html ?